# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 problem for 64-bit machine

Tags: oledb, 32bit-64bit

I am working on Visual Basics using Visual Studio 2008, my application is to read the data from the Microsoft Access database and plot the graph using Crystal Reports.

For accessing to database I need to use a method:

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=D:\a.mdb";
```

Which is working fine in 32-bit machine but i try to run it on 64-bit machine I am getting the error:

> Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

So can any one help me out how to resolve this? I need it run it on 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Access 64 bit redistributable from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

After you install it, you can use `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` for this version of 64 bit OLEDB.

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties → Build, change your "Platform target" to x86, then it will find the 32 bit driver.